# How to prevent a user from login in, but allow "su - user" in Linux?

Tags: linux, login, su

How do you allow a user to log in using "`su -` *user*" but prevent the user from login in using SSH?

I tried to set the shell to `/bin/false` but the when I try to `su` it doesn't work.

Are there several ways to only allow logins by `su`?

Is SSH's `AllowUser` the way to go? (how would I do this if it's the way to go)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use *AllowUsers* / *AllowGroups* if you have only a few users/groups that are allowed to login via ssh or *DenyUsers* / *DenyGroups* if you have only a few users/groups that are *not* allowed to login. Note that this only restricts login via ssh, other ways of login (console, ftp, ...) are still possible. You need to add these options to your */etc/ssh/sshd_config* file for most ssh installations.

If you have set the login shell to */bin/false* you can use `su -s /bin/bash user` (replace */bin/bash* with the shell of your choice)

Comment: thanks a lot to all.  I didn't expect to get 2+ upvotes on my question :)   I like the *"su -s ..."* construct a lot and the console/ftp is a good point.  I was really after something like "su -s".

Comment: The su -s trick is gold.  I use it all the time for system accounts I need to test permissions for, e.g., apache, nobody, etc.  I usually do su - user -s /bin/bash.  The optional argument - may be used to provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.

Comment: If you need environment variables (e.g. from /etc/profile) to be loaded, passing an extra dash will do it: `su - -s /bin/bash user`

Answer (score 13):

If you still want su to work, you can use `sudo -u [username]` or pass `-s /bin/bash` to su as a temporary shell. They both do the same in absence of a shell in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 10):

If an account has no password (*passwd -d username*), they can't log in interactively (console, SSH, etc.).  If they have a valid shell, *su* will still work.  Note the "interactively," though; if somebody decides to set up an SSH keypair for the account, it will work!

Comment: does the user need to have a valid shell to su? I'm pretty sure you're still in the same original shell after you su to another user... you don't actually LOG IN as the other user... So, just setting the shell to /dev/null might work aswell.

Comment: Yep, it still needs a valid shell:

[root@localhost ~]# su daemon
This account is currently not available.
[root@localhost ~]# su - daemon
This account is currently not available.

(RHEL system, daemon's shell is /sbin/nologin)

Answer (score 3):

In sshd_config add a line `DenyUser [username]`

Note that this will not prevent that user from logging in via the console.

Comment: That should be `DenyUsers`, with an 's'.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what's been mentioned above (disable and/or not setting the user password), pam_access module (look up man page on pam_access and access.conf) can be used to control login access.

Answer (score 1):

as others have said;

`DenyUser username` or `DenyGroup groupname` in `sshd_config` would prevent keypair/password login via ssh.

though i usually do something like `AllowGroup ssh` or something along those lines, and explicitly add people who need ssh access to that group.

then, you can do as other's have said: `passwd -d username` to blank out the users password, so they cannot log in at the console, or some other way. or better yet `passwd -l username` to 'lock' the account. it is possible ssh will deny access to a locked account, even with keys, but i'm not positive.

Comment: Actually ssh will allow you to log in using key authentication even when the account password is locked.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing which mechanism is best depends on the requirements.  If you know the requirements, you can choose the appropriate mechanism.  All of the above answers are valid for some set of requirements.

Do you only want to restrict SSH access?  Do you need access for mail or ssh methods?  Is access only from root?

`su - user` will require a password for user if it is run be a user other than root.  However, `sudo -u user -i` does not require a password for user.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, I think that you can still su into an account with an invalid shell. So if you set the user's shell to /dev/null or whatever the shell of bin is, you should be able to still su into that user... but any attempt to log in in any way will quit you back out...

Answer (score 1):

edit /etc/shadow by adding ! to the beginning of the password hash.

```
username:!<hash>:#####:#:#####:#:::
```

When securing a new install this is the first thing I do after installing sudo, so nobody is able to use the root user to login or ssh into the system, sudo users may still execute as root user.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify a password for the user not allowed to log in or delete it.

```
# passwd -d myuser
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to su user from root's account, and disable all other access:

Use this (run as root):

```
usermod -e 1 -L user
```

This disables password login (as many other answers have advised), **but it also expires the account**. You can't login to an expired account, e.g. with SSH keys. You can still `su user`, although it will display a notice that the account has expired.